# Self-invoking function javascript

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

I've tried to write this code for self-invoking function in Javascript:

```
var ello = ("ello");
obj = (function myFunc(){var elem= []["H" + ello]["world"]["!" + "!"]();
 return elem;
}, "as");

test = myFunc();
```

But at the last line I received this error message:

- myFunc is not defined

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to achieve by just reading that code. You'll have to explain what you are trying to do because the code itself doesn't look like anything.

Comment: why you are using brackets around function declaration, this `var elem= []["H" + ello]["world"]["!" + "!"]();` is just nonsense.

Comment: There are quite a few errors and unnecessary brackets in the code, and the function is not self-invoking. As Sergui says, you need to lay out exactly what steps you think the code should be making.

Comment: While myFunc is not "self-invoking" (you clearly attempt to invoke it later), it's also *private* to obj, which is why you get "not defined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't written a self-invoking function.

You've written a named function expression.

Named function expressions generate a variable with the same name as them only *inside their own scope* (as opposed to function declarations which generate a variable with the same name in the scope in which the function was declared).

In order to call a function expression you have to either immediately invoke it (by following it with `()`) or assign it to a variable or property to call later. You are doing neither (while you do have an assignment operator just before it, the comma operator afterwards means that the string `"as"` gets assigned instead).

(Note that the function you have written will throw errors when you call it. It makes no sense at all.)

Comment: Ak. I misread that as being part of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a self invoking function:

```
var ello = 'ello';
var result = function() { return 'H' + ello}()
console.log(result) // outputs > Hello
```